# Align div top to the bottom of a sibling div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to place the `dropdownContainer` below the `inputContainer`, but without the `dropdownContainer` being encased within `autocompleteContainer`.

When scrolled, the `dropdownContainer` should move with the `inputContainer`. Same when the token divs are removed or added.

If I remove position:absolute from the `dropdownContainer` it aligns correctly, but appears inside `autocompleteContainer`

I would prefer to do this without JS/jQuery, but I'll use it if there is no other option.

Here's a codepen link: http://codepen.io/rishadjb/pen/LRxzpN

Thank you.

```css
.mainContainer{
  width:700px;
    position: relative;
}
.autocompleteContainer{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ececec;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
/*   height:60px; */
    max-height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 4px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    cursor: text;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.token{
      background-color: #f7982f;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

.inputContainer{
      flex-grow: 1;
  position:relative;
}

.autoCompleteInput{
      border: medium none;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px 12px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #008cc1;  
}

.dropdownContainer{
  height:60px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  z-index:999;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="autocompleteContainer">
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenToken</div>
    <div class="token">TokenTokenTokenToken</div>
    
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input class="autoCompleteInput" value='inputText'/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdownContainer">Dropdown Container</div>
  
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the `.autocompleteContainer` has to float? If you remove that declaration, then all you need to do is to add to `dropdownContainer`:

```
.dropdownContainer{
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it align the dropdownContainer to the bottom of the autocompleteContainer , not the inputContainer. Codepen: https://codepen.io/rishadjb/pen/Kgaygd